# Can Dragonrot kill/incapacitate some NPCs making some interactions impossible after a bunch of deaths?

Tags: sekiro-shadows-die-twice

When NPCs talk about Dragonrot, it really seems that at some point the dragonrot can kill.

Thing is, if it does kill some major NPCs, it would make some functions impossible; example, if the sculptor would be to die, how can I equip new shinobi tools?

So can Dragonrot kill some NPCs and thus making interactions or even quests impossible later in the story, or is Dragonrot just making the Unseen aid go down but not much else?

Also, if it does kill, what things should I look for as signs that an NPC is going to die soon and I should cure it asap? (and death's door lines or something like that?)

Comment: !SPOILER ALERT!                                                                                                                         the sculptor actually vanishes at some point and you are still able to create and upgrade prostethics

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dragonrot doesn't kill NPCs. What it does is halting their questlines until you cure them.

Answer (score 0):

Some people are mistakenly thinking, that Dragonrot has killed some of the NPCs in their game, but it is actually due to some characters questlines. Dragonrot itself doesn't kill NPCs.

Moreover, apparently Dragonrot is capable to "block" NPCs death, as you are not progressing their questline. Example:

> Inosuke Nogami and his mother are dying once you kill Lady Butterfly as part of their questline. However, if they are infected by Dragonrot, they are kept alive until you cure it.